# Take Screenshot when Sound (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, automation, screenshot, alsa

I have this program which would give me an acoustic alert (beep) when a certain event occurs.

Now i want to write a script (preferably in bash or python) that takes a screenshot right after that beep occurs and saves it to a destined folder; how could one do that on Linux?

I suppose somehow monitoring the ALSA master output and then scrot when a certain dB threshold is reached? What would be a good way to implement this?

Comment: Is this a command line program? If so it probably beeps just by printing `\a`. A tool that creates a pty like `script` could intercept that and trigger actions. If you don't have latency requirements, you could even work directly with a `script` log and create all the screenshots after the fact in two lines of shell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No it is not command line, in fact it is my Chromium browser having open a website which sends out alerts. I would want to make it universally usable though.